# Счетчик от заданного дня на WordPress

Tags: wordpress

Мне понадобился счетчик от конкретного дня и до остановки отсчета.

На каком языке будет проще, и меньше кода - лучше, думаю это было бы на PHP проще.

Что надо: я ввожу день, и с этого дня идет счет, но чтобы отображался он так: 30 дней 12 часов.

Так же понадобится вывод этого счетчика на странице. Подскажите как его вывести, с оформлением текста на CSS разберусь.

P.S счетчик будет отдельный для определенных записей, чтобы я мог вывести несколько одновременно, например 30 и результаты были разные везде.

Comment: За Вас здесь никто не будет писать код, вам с таким вопросом лучше обращаться к фрилансерам или покорять просторы интернета. Тут решают проблемы и помогают разобраться в вопросах, а не писать за кого-то их задумки "за так" / выполнять д/з  и т.п.

Comment: Я спросила, на каком языке это будет лучше сделать? И как лучше реализовать, чтобы выводить несколько счетчиков на разных страницах.

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы счетчик работал в браузере без перезагрузки страницы - нужен javascript. Доводилось делать такие счетчики.

Начальные параметры этот скрипт должен брать из элемента с определенным классом, из свойства `data`, например. А уж выводить на страницу такие элементы должен код php, в котором надо задать день окончания счета.